# HtmlAgilityPack pulling extra text from a block of html

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to extract certain parts of a web page, but I am having some trouble.  I am very new to the web parsing so please assume I know nothing and keep answers very detailed.

I have this section of html

```
<div id="playerStats">
  <div id="hp"><span class="title">HP:</span>"12213"</div>
  <div id="mp"><span class="title">MP:</span></div>
  <div id="magicResist"><span class="title">Magic Resist</span>"4618"</div>
  <div id="physicalDefend"><span class="title">Physical Defence</span>"1725"</div>
  <div id="phyCriticalReduceRate"><span class="title">Strike Resist</span>"1518"</div>
  <div id="phyCriticalDamageReduce"><span class="title">Strike fortitude</span>"392"</div>
  <div id="physicalRight"><span class="title">Main Hand Attack</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="accuracyRight"><span class="title">Main Hand Accuracy</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="criticalRight"><span class="title">Main Hand Critical</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="physicalLeft"><span class="title">Off Hand Attack</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="accuracyLeft"><span class="title">Off Hand Accuracy</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="criticalLeft"><span class="title">Off Hand Critical</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="attackSpeed"><span class="title">Attack Speed</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="magicalBoost"><span class="title">Magic Boost</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="magicalAccuracy"><span class="title">Magic Accuracy</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="magicalCriticalRight"><span class="title">Crit Spell</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="castingTimeRatio"><span class="title">Casting Speed</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="block"><span class="title">Block</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="dodge"><span class="title">Evasion</span>"201"</div>
</div>
```

Which gives an output of

```
HP:
MP:
Magic Resist
Physical Defence
Strike Resist
Strike fortitude
Main Hand Attack
Main Hand Accuracy
Main Hand Critical
Off Hand Attack
Off Hand Accuracy
Off Hand Critical
Attack Speed
Magic Boost
Magic Accuracy
Crit Spell
Casting Speed
Block
Evasion
Movement Speed
```

using the code

```
var browser = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"playerStats\"]");
if (browser != null) {
  foreach(var b in browser)
  output.AppendLine(b.InnerHtml);
} else {
  output.AppendLine(("Oops!  I'm broken!"));
}
```

However, I also would like to include the number "12213" or any text in between the

```
</span>"xxx"</div>
```

after lets say "HP:"

How can I retrieve this text as well using the code I already have implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this (in a console app sample):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(MyTestFile);

foreach(var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='playerStats']/div/span"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText + " " + (node.NextSibling != null ? node.NextSibling.InnerText : null));
}
```

NextSibling is the next node after a given node with the same parent. It may not exist if the current node is the last child of a parent.

Note I have explicitely set element types to DIV for initial selection as it's better in terms of performance. (* matches any node).

Comment: Thank You! This section of code works perfectly with the html code from above. However, whenever I fetch the html code from the webside using the var document = web.Load(rawHtmlAddressString); it does not get any of the numerical values I am trying to receive as well. Only the output which is described above. However, if I look at the html code through Chrome with the F-12 function at the page, the numerical values are there. Any ideas?  [Answer at this question if you do!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390780/htmlagilitypack-isnt-getting-all-the-html-code-text-from-a-web-page)

Comment: This is because a browser builds an in-memory DOM representation that does not match what has been read from the wire, because it's modified by javascript dynamically. Html Agility Pack only get what comes from HTTP, it's not a browser. So you can't use smart developer tools built in the browsers (inspect, F12, etc...) to determine XPATH, or HTML, etc.