# HtmlAgilityPack isn't getting all the html code/text from a web page

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

For starters, thank you in advance!

I am able to extract a section of code from a web page that looks similar to the following block of code.

```
<div id="playerStats">
  <div id="hp"><span class="title">HP:</span></div>
  <div id="mp"><span class="title">MP:</span></div>
  <div id="magicResist"><span class="title">Magic Resist</span></div>
  <div id="physicalDefend"><span class="title">Physical Defence</span></div>
  <div id="phyCriticalReduceRate"><span class="title">Strike Resist</span></div>
  <div id="phyCriticalDamageReduce"><span class="title">Strike fortitude</span></div>
  <div id="physicalRight"><span class="title">Main Hand Attack</span></div>
  <div id="accuracyRight"><span class="title">Main Hand Accuracy</span></div>
  <div id="criticalRight"><span class="title">Main Hand Critical</span></div>
  <div id="physicalLeft"><span class="title">Off Hand Attack</span></div>
  <div id="accuracyLeft"><span class="title">Off Hand Accuracy</span></div>
  <div id="criticalLeft"><span class="title">Off Hand Critical</span></div>
  <div id="attackSpeed"><span class="title">Attack Speed</span></div>
  <div id="magicalBoost"><span class="title">Magic Boost</span></div>
  <div id="magicalAccuracy"><span class="title">Magic Accuracy</span></div>
  <div id="magicalCriticalRight"><span class="title">Crit Spell</span></div>
  <div id="castingTimeRatio"><span class="title">Casting Speed</span></div>
  <div id="block"><span class="title">Block</span></div>
  <div id="dodge"><span class="title">Evasion</span></div>
</div>
```

from the following uri [for this character statistics page of a video game. (And you should clearly see the table of stats in the middle of the page.)](http://psykopats.net/Kahrun/c/299345)
If you use your browser's function similar to Google Chrome's F-12 to view the html source code, you will notice there are values in between /span and /div similar to the following code:

```
<div id="playerStats">
  <div id="hp"><span class="title">HP:</span>"12213"</div>
  <div id="mp"><span class="title">MP:</span>"4000"</div>
  <div id="magicResist"><span class="title">Magic Resist</span>"4618"</div>
  <div id="physicalDefend"><span class="title">Physical Defence</span>"1725"</div>
  <div id="phyCriticalReduceRate"><span class="title">Strike Resist</span>"1518"</div>
  <div id="phyCriticalDamageReduce"><span class="title">Strike fortitude</span>"392"</div>
  <div id="physicalRight"><span class="title">Main Hand Attack</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="accuracyRight"><span class="title">Main Hand Accuracy</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="criticalRight"><span class="title">Main Hand Critical</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="physicalLeft"><span class="title">Off Hand Attack</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="accuracyLeft"><span class="title">Off Hand Accuracy</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="criticalLeft"><span class="title">Off Hand Critical</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="attackSpeed"><span class="title">Attack Speed</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="magicalBoost"><span class="title">Magic Boost</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="magicalAccuracy"><span class="title">Magic Accuracy</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="magicalCriticalRight"><span class="title">Crit Spell</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="castingTimeRatio"><span class="title">Casting Speed</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="block"><span class="title">Block</span>"201"</div>
  <div id="dodge"><span class="title">Evasion</span>"201"</div>
</div>
```

And to go on, I am using the following code to retrieve the first block of html code described above.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(MyTestFile);

foreach(var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='playerStats']/div/span"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText + " " + (node.NextSibling != null ?  node.NextSibling.InnerText : null));
}
```

I have used the WebRequest, WebClient, WebBrowser and HtmlWeb-agilitypack classes to pull the html document down from the web.  However, the most important part from which I wish to extract is not being pulled down in the document which is the values associated with Hp, mp, etc... The expected values are described in the second block of html code above.

How can I get my code to bring down this simple text in the document for me to parse as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player info is loaded dynamically by calling `http://psykopats.net/loadAion.php` with POST method and a few parameters, one of which is `player` and identifies the player. In your case, the parameters were:

```
server:66
type:1
player:299345
```

You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290390/send-post-with-webclient-downloadstring-in-c-sharp) to see how to use POST with `WebClient`.

The response is a JSON string that, among other things, contains what you are looking for:

```
stat: {baseCriticalResist:0, magicCriticalResist:0, physicalDefend:1402, baseMagicalSpeed:1,…}
accuracyLeft: 2617
accuracyRight: 2617
agi: 110
airResist: 0
attackSpeed: 1.1
baseAccuracyLeft: 1705
baseAccuracyRight: 1705
baseAgi: 110
baseAirResist: 0
baseAttackSpeed: 1.1
baseBlock: 837
baseCastingTimeRatio: "1.0"
baseCriticalDefend: 0
baseCriticalLeft: 53
baseCriticalResist: 0
baseCriticalRight: 103
baseDex: 110
baseDodge: 1839
baseDp: 4000
baseEarthResist: 0
baseFireResist: 0
baseHealBoost: 0
baseHealSkillBoost: 0
baseHp: 6688
baseKno: 90
baseMagCriticalDamageReduce: 0
baseMagCriticalReduceRate: 0
baseMagicCriticalDefend: 0
baseMagicCriticalResist: 0
baseMagicResist: 1384
baseMagicalAccuracy: ""
baseMagicalAttack: 0
baseMagicalBoost: 0
baseMagicalCriticalLeft: 50
baseMagicalCriticalRight: 50
baseMagicalSpeed: 1
baseMoveSpeed: 6
baseMp: 4318
baseParry: 1847
basePhyCriticalDamageReduce: 0
basePhyCriticalReduceRate: 190
basePhysicalDefend: 1162
basePhysicalLeft: 255
basePhysicalRight: 234
baseStr: 110
baseVit: 100
baseWaterResist: 0
baseWill: ""
block: 837
castingTimeRatio: 0.98
criticalDefend: 0
criticalLeft: 602
criticalResist: 0
criticalRight: ""
dex: 110
dodge: 2272
dp: 4000
earthResist: ""
fireResist: 0
healBoost: 0
healSkillBoost: 0
hp: 11210
kno: 90
magCriticalDamageReduce: 0
magCriticalReduceRate: 38
magicCriticalDefend: 0
magicCriticalResist: 0
magicResist: 1725
magicalAccuracy: 1201
magicalAttack: 0
magicalBoost: 0
magicalCriticalLeft: 50
magicalCriticalRight: 50
magicalSpeed: "1.0"
moveSpeed: 7.56
mp: 4618
parry: ""
phyCriticalDamageReduce: 201
phyCriticalReduceRate: 392
physicalDefend: 1402
physicalLeft: 658
physicalRight: 658
str: 110
vit: 100
waterResist: 0
will: 0
```

Sample code:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
byte[] data = wc.UploadValues(
    "http://psykopats.net/loadAion.php",
    new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection(){
        {"server", "66"},
        {"type", "1"},
        {"player", "299345"}});
string json = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```